# Using a parameter in oracle query in pyspark

Tags: oracle, pyspark

I want to define a parameter that I will use in some queries in Oracle (through PySpark):

```
week='2020 w21'
query=  f""" ( select*from table where week_in_year=week)main """
```

But unfortunately reading this gives me an error
`ORA-00904: "week": invalid identifier`

The column "week_in_year" is also a string. How can I use this parameter in a query?

Comment: Then I get an error `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify {} for f string and enclose the week value in single quote

```
week="'2020 w21'"
query=  f""" ( select*from table where week_in_year={week} )main """
```